# ubuntu 17.04 problem at logging in

Tags: apt, sudo, lightdm, 17.04

so i have a know issue of being stuck at a login screen and the problems is even after running the solution of 
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove lightdm
 and reinstalling it 
 it only lasts a short period of time before I get stuck at the login again. I really don't want to delete ubuntu and install it again as I have done that last hours. My question is how do I make this permanent solution?

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Does the lock screen "freeze", so that you cannot click any buttons or enter any text into the password field? Are you running a dedicated graphics card? If so, have you tried installing the latest driver for it?

Comment: after login everythings freeze the mouse doesn't move and the icons don't load so basically a purple screen with the shutdown and time showing but are not "clickable"